# Paper element import not working in python

Tags: django, python-3.x, polymer, polymer-3.x

Paper elements are not able to import in python-django environment, and
an import error arises

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@polymer/polymer/polymer-legacy.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I've tried to build the same project using `polymer build` still there is no improvement.

I've placed the polymer components inside a static folder in an app
`My project -> App-> static -> polymer files`

Environment details:

```
OS: ubuntu 18.04
Lang: python 3.6- django 1.11
polymer version: 3
```

The error is from the js files present in the node_modules folder which is part of polymer project

Comment: try `polymer build; http-server build/default 
`

Comment: @ Yugandhar Chaudhari We have to run django by using the command python manage.py runserver right so this command cannot be used there at root folder

Comment: Any idea on this issue?