# How do I use Polymer elements as static resources in a Flask application?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, polymer

I'm using a Flask backend, but I want a javascript framework that I can inject for a handful of custom components, and not the whole page. I've tried out Angular and React, and now I'm trying to get a working version that uses Polymer 3.0. However, I'm having trouble with imports, and or building the elements, before attempting to import them into the flask template page.

The only way I've gotten it to work thus far is by:

flask_template.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<body>
    <base href="/demo_polymer">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    {% block body %}
    <script src="/static/polymer-assets/node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/static/polymer-assets/polymer-switch.js"></script>
    <div id="switch">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
                <span class="card-title">Switch</span>
                <form id="form_name">
                    <div>
                        <polymer-switch id="switch1" name="sliderSwitch" checked></polymer-switch>
                    </div>
                    <input id="testInputText" name="testInputText" type="text" value="testInputText">
                    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

polymer-switch.js

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

class PolymerSwitch extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style>
        :host {}
      </style>
      <div class="slider-switch" >
        <input class="slider-input" type="checkbox" checked={{checked}}>
        <div class="slider-groove">
          <span class="slider-button"></span>
          <span class="slider-content"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      checked: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      }
    };
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('slider-switch created!');
  }
  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    console.log('slider-switch connected!');
  }
  ready() {
    super.ready();
  }
}
window.customElements.define('polymer-switch', PolymerSwitch);
```

And go into every imported javascript module to change "@something..." into "/static/polymer-assets/node_modules/@something..."

However, this is then importing each module, and I want to just import one file that lets me use the element anywhere in my flask template after I import the file describing it. I haven't been able to use the command "polymer build --js-compile" (or any variation of it), to give me a file I can use. Usually its giving me an html file, and importing it warns me that it won't be supported anymore by March, and doesn't render the custom element.

It's just difficult to work out how it should work when:

- Polymer is on its third revision, so every tutorial I lookup may not have the right syntax.
- I'm trying to use it in a nonstandard way (as far as I can tell), by having it as an add-on rather than as a single page application.
- I can quite wrap my head around how to build the javascript files into a single javascript file that I could then import into my page and use.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54567339/paper-element-import-not-working-in-python