# Use Polymer3 with django

Tags: python, django, polymer-3.x

How to import basic polymer 3 components like paper-elements and iron elements in django.

Polymer1 components(html pages) can be imported using materialdjango, but it does not support polymer3.
see documentation:-[documentation of material django](https://github.com/Colorless-Green-Ideas/MaterialDjango)

error while trying to import paper button element

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@polymer/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

## base.html

```
<!-- templates/base.html -->
{% load static %}
{% load polymerdep %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>{% block title %}Django {% endblock %}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  <script src="{% static "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js" %}"></script>
  <script type="module" src="{% static "src/components-app/components-app.js" %}"></script>
  <script type="module" src="{% static "src/components-app/header-element.js" %}"></script>
  <script type="module" src="{% static "src/components-app/button-element.js" %}"></script>
  <script type="module" src="{% static "src/components-app/dropdown-element.js" %}"></script>
  <script type="module">
    import '../static/node_modules/@polymer/paper-button/paper-button.js';
  </script>
  {% block link %} {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the "link" is actually paper button defined in

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Welcome
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Testtt</h1>

<a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a>
<a href="{% url 'signup' %}">signup</a>
<button-element title='test'></button-element>
<dropdown-element></dropdown-element>
<paper-button class="pink" >link</paper-button>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @9769953 There was an old question asked by me . I posted a new one because no one responded for that.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54567339/paper-element-import-not-working-in-python

Comment: @9769953 updated question and added error image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paper element import not working in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54567339/paper-element-import-not-working-in-python)

Comment: Polymer included in base.html edited my question

Comment: if we remove that line the polymer element doesn't call up

no console error or no change in button style

Comment: while using polymer components alone that example holds good.

In case of python relative paths must be specified and as the error states relative paths should not start with @

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188740/discussion-between-sanjeev-s-and-9769953).